# Nested String Operations in ASP

Tags: html, asp.net, tcl

I am trying to nest string operations in ASP, but I am getting errors. I'm new to this, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be great. Here's what I have:

Form Page:

```
<form method="post" action="ping.asp">
Subnet: <input type="text" name="subnet" value="XXX.XXX.XXX"><br>
First IP: <input type="text" name="first_ip" value="XXX"><br>
Last IP: <input type="text" name="last_ip" value="YYY"><br>
<input type="radio" name="OS" value="CISCO" /> IOS 
<input type="radio" name="OS" value="CMD" /> Command Prompt <br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

ASP File:

```
<%
strHeading = "<h1>IOS AND COMMAND PROMPT RANGE PING BUILDER" & "</h1>"

strOS = Request.Form ("OS")
if strOS ="CISCO" then
strWrite = "<br>tclsh<br>for {set n <%=request.querystring("first_ip")%>} {$n<=<%=request.querystring("last_ip")%>} {incr n} {<br>if { [regexp &#34;(!)&#34; [exec &#34;ping <%= Request.QueryString("subnet") %>.$n timeout 1 repeat 1&#34; ]] } {<br>puts &#34;<%=Request.QueryString("subnet")%>.$n&#34;<br>          } else { puts &#34;<%=Request.QueryString("subnet")%>.$n **** failed ***&#34; }<br>          }<br><br>"

elseif strOS ="CMD" then
strWrite = "<br>for /L %z in (< % Request.QueryString("first_ip")% >,1,< % Request.QueryString("last_ip")% >) do @ping < % Request.QueryString("subnet"% >.%z -w 10 -n 1 | find &#34;Reply&#34;<br>"

else
strWrite = "Please select either IOS or Command Prompt."
End if
%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Range Ping Creator</title>
</head>
<body align=center>

<% Response.Write strHeading %>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<% Response.Write strWrite %> 
<br>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

It should output the following based on the radio selection. It works fine if i replace the strWrite text with plain text, but not with the operations. Any hints?

Proper output:

for /L %z in (XXX,1,YYY) do @ping XXX.XXX.XXX.%z -w 10 -n 1 | find "Reply"

tclsh
for {set n XXX} {$n<=YYY} {incr n} {
if { [regexp "(!)" [exec "ping XXX.XXX.XXX.$n timeout 1 repeat 1" ]] } {
puts "XXX.XXX.XXX.$n"
          } else { puts "XXX.XXX.XXX.$n **** failed ***" }
          }

Answer (score 0):

The way classic ASP works string concatenation is like this (it uses the ampersand to concatenate):

```
strWrite = myOS & " some string here " & request.querystring("some_ip") & " and then more stuff."
```

When you're in an executing block of code (  stuff between <% and %>    it's all regular VBScript/ASP stuff, no more need to inline code (using <%= and %>)

```
<%
strWrite = myOS & " is an operating system using the IP: " & request.querystring("ip_address") & "!"

'do more stuff here

%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE><%=mystring_title_variable_here%></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Hey there, folks.  This is what I know:
<P><%=strWrite%></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Gives an example of using them both ways.